# What does root directory mean?

Tags: linux, terminal, patch

What does it means when they say

> "Move into the root directory of the kernel you wish to patch"

Comment: Please review the help files to see what is considered a good question. This is not one. It’s clear that you have not done any research on your own.

Comment: Don't try to patch the kernel if you are so new to Linux. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) to get a broad picture, and read several books on Linux system administration before touching the kernel.

Comment: what if a accidentally write a wrong command while building a kernel??, will it harm my system or it will just create a error in terminal?? @Jakuje

Comment: Hi Shri. Just use Linux for a while. Get used to the environment, its many tools and the subsystms that are relevant to you. If you have a reason to patch a kernel (I did not, after 10+ years of extensive linux usage!) you can proceed :) If you want to take a rough ride that will take you into the guts of your system, install archlinux or gentoo. You might be served better with a more beginner friendly distribution, though. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, root directory is referring to the top-level directory of the kernel source that you want to patch. That depends on what distribution of Linux you are using and where they install the kernel source.